# IObservable in Silverlight 4 : type or namespace IObservable could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

Where can I find this class? I have included the Rx extensions. I have made sure the version I'm compiling to is Silverlight 4. My VS2010 IDE still has no idea what the type IObservable is.

I get a compile error saying "type or namespace IObservable could not be found"

I didn't see them in the System.Collections.Generic namespace like this thread suggests
http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/523437-include-iobserver-t-and-iobservable-t-interface

Am I missing a reference to a dll?

Comment: I think IObservable was added to the core .NET 4 libraries. But what is the story with Silverlight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the System namespace, the type is IObservable<T>. You'll need to add a reference to System.Observable.dll from the ReactiveExtensions SDK.

Also, while not strictly required, you'll probably want to add a reference to System.Reactive.dll, which contains numerous extension methods to operate on IObservable<T>.

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very long answers, but there's not a lot to say.

Silverlight only uses a [small subset of the .NET Framework](http://www.vistadb.net/blog/post/2009/12/08/Does-Silverlight-4-really-use-Net-4-assemblies.aspx). That said, [IObservable isn't included in Silverlight 4](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/523437-include-iobserver-t-and-iobservable-t-interface) if you don't include (reference) the System.Reactive.dll